# API method for getting window's controls

Tags: c++, api

I've searched quite a while in MSDN, couldn't find it.

In fact, I don't even know how controls are called in API. they are not declared as a "Window", right? (No hwnd for them, I wasn't sure because I saw a method which seemed like it could return a control but it returns an hwnd.)

So lets say I have a window's handle. I want to recieve it's controls (a textbox, button, checkbox....)

What are the methods to do this? And again, how are the controls called in API? 
Thanks for helpers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're called Windows and HWNDs are handles to these windows, just like a `fopen()` returns a handle to a file.
[These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468919%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) are all the functions you'll need. Try `EnumChildWindows`

Comment: [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also extremely useful for getting a dialog box's controls.

Comment: So a handle to a control is STILL called a hwnd. Okay and I have looked at EnumChildWindows already, but then I have no idea how can I decide which handle is the one I need. Any ideas on that?

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for. If you know the HMENU used to create said control (e.g. you created the window) then you can use, as Adam suggested, `GetDlgItem`. Otherwise, you should find some distinguishing property of said control and check for it (e.g. class name, title, etc.)

Comment: I don't know the hMenu, the program is supposed to be generic. But I have looked now in MSDN, and it says HWND hDlg is a handle to a dialog box. Does a window count as a dialog box? But yet, how can I find the identifier of the control? (nIDDlgItem)